# How do I inherit from an abstract UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

If I have a class

```
abstract class DetailsForm : UserControl
```

then

```
AppDetailsForm : DetailsForm
BoxDetailsForm : DetailsForm
```

I can take advantage of inheritance to stick logic in `DetailsForm.cs` that applies to elements common among the  tags in `AppDetailsForm.aspx` and `BoxDetailsForm.aspx`. These tags appear in both, in exactly the same place. There is duplicated header and footer code in `AppDetailsForm.aspx` and `BoxDetailsForm.aspx` that I'd rather stick in `DetailsForm.cs`.

The problem is I would need to stick a reference in `DetailsForm.aspx` that would refer to the content of the .aspx file in a child derived directly from that class.

However, currently, it only shows the content of `AppDetailsForm.aspx` or `BoxDetailsForm.aspx`, and ignores anything in `DetailsForm.cs`, so it seems like the reference to the other file should go `AppDetailsForm.aspx` → `DetailsForm.cs` and `BoxDetailsForm.aspx` → `DetailsForm.cs`.

I don't know how to do this, and I suspect I'm approaching this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Master pages are built for what you are trying to do.

Take a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx).